# QtDBus. How to call a method taking a QDBusUnixFileDescriptor as parameter

Tags: qt, qtdbus

I have a D-Bus method that takes a `QDBusUnixFileDescriptor` as a parameter. But I do not know how to call this method via the bus.

The documentation for `QDBusUnixFileDescriptor` states:

> This allows applications to send and receive Unix file descriptors over 
>   the D-Bus connection, mapping automatically to the D-Bus type 'h'.

To call other methods I am using `QDBusInterface::call` which takes the method name and a bunch of `QVariant`s. `QVariant` is not implemented for `QDBusUnixFileDescriptor`.

I've been unable to locate any examples either in Qt documentation, at github, or with google.

How can I call a bus method that takes a `QDBusUnixFileDescriptor` as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I am rather new in Qt, but as good as I know you can check

```cpp
QVariant::fromValue(yourQDBusUnixFileDescriptor)
```

Good luck